# Drop down menu on click show hide structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to make my own reservation form based on few parameters, in fact I would like to have a structure of drop down menu, where one drop down menu shows other after user clicked it.

For example:

```
<select id="location">
  <option>Choose location</option>
  <option value="location_a">Location A</option>
  <option value="location_b">Location B</option>
  <option value="location_c">Location C</option>
</select>
```

After the user click on Location A, or B or C browser need to show other drop down:

```
<select id="location_a">
  <option>Choose location</option>
  <option value="hotel_a">Hotel A</option>
  <option value="hotel_b">Hotel B</option>
  <option value="hotel_c">Hotel C</option>
</select>

<select id="location_b">
  <option>Choose location</option>
  <option value="hotel_a">Hotel A</option>
  <option value="hotel_b">Hotel B</option>
  <option value="hotel_c">Hotel C</option>
</select>

<select id="location_c">
  <option>Choose location</option>
  <option value="hotel_a">Hotel A</option>
  <option value="hotel_b">Hotel B</option>
  <option value="hotel_c">Hotel C</option>
</select>
```

After the buyer click on Hotel browser need to show previuosly two drop down and the third:

```
<select id="microlocation">
  <option>Choose location</option>
  <option value="micro_a">Micro location A</option>
  <option value="micro_b">Micro location B</option>
  <option value="micro_c">Micro location C</option>
</select>
```

when select micro location, need to show

```
<div class="micro_c">Address of Micro C location</div>
```

etc.

Thank You for help.

I've tried search for show/hide div jQuery, but this works only with one level.

Best regards

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? Where's the jQuery you tried and you're having issues with? Please make always sure to provide a [mcve], currently I see no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to program it:  I checks the value of the select and if it isn't default, then it continues to display down the list.

```js
$("#location_b, #location_c").hide();

$("select").on("change", function() {
  $("select").hide();
  if ($("#location_a").show().val() != "default") {
    if ($("#location_b").show().val() != "default") {
      $("#location_c").show();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="location_a">
   <option value="default">Choose location</option>
   <option value="hotel_a">Hotel A</option>
   <option value="hotel_b">Hotel B</option>
   <option value="hotel_c">Hotel C</option>
 </select>

<select id="location_b">
   <option value="default">Choose location</option>
   <option value="hotel_a">Hotel A</option>
   <option value="hotel_b">Hotel B</option>
   <option value="hotel_c">Hotel C</option>
 </select>

<select id="location_c">
   <option value="default">Choose location</option>
   <option value="hotel_a">Hotel A</option>
   <option value="hotel_b">Hotel B</option>
   <option value="hotel_c">Hotel C</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Instead of modifying you've could just do `if(this.value)`

Comment: Good idea, I'll change that in a bit

Comment: BTW the code and OP's request makes totally no sense. Even your implementation - due to lack of description and code samples from OP's side is odd. Jut for example - what if someone (after all three selects are visible) goes "back one step", what should than happen? The question si too broad.

Comment: The user is now allowed to go back one and select "choose location," hiding the rest.

Comment: Still makes no sense :) but that's up to OP.

Comment: I know, conceptually, what OP is, but I am wondering what does the two letters actually stand for?

Comment: OP Stands for Original Poster - the author of the Question.